# Which private repos have GitHub Pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I want to downgrade my GitHub account to the free plan. GitHub warns me that I have one private repository that uses GitHub Pages - a feature that the free plan doesn't support. So I want to find this repo to see if it is problematic if it becomes public.

I can't find any way to even list my repos that use Github Pages, let alone the ones that are private.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, simple via [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql), with or without [GraphQL API Explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer), (don't forget personal access token scope if using without the explorer,) if you don't have very much private repos.

Use query:

```
query { 
  viewer {
    repositories (first:100, privacy: PRIVATE) {
      nodes {
        name
        deployments (first: 1) {
          nodes {
            environment
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example result:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "viewer": {
      "repositories": {
        "nodes": [
          {
            "name": "repo-without-pages",
            "deployments": {
              "nodes": []
            }
          },
          {
            "name": "repo-with-pages",
            "deployments": {
              "nodes": [
                {
                  "environment": "github-pages"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Typically the only possible environment is github-pages. If you have more, change the above query.

Note GitHub GraphQL API has a limit: Values of `first` and `last` must be within 1-100. If you have more than 100, use:

```
    repositories (first:100, privacy: PRIVATE) {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
      }
```

and after getting `endCursor`:

```
    repositories (first:100, privacy: PRIVATE, after:"endCursorValue==") {
      pageInfo {
        endCursor
      }
```

to paginate.

Comment: For me, this also seems to return results that don't have any `environment` children. It's not a big deal, I can just search through for the Github Pages one. But I wonder if the query could be improved.

Comment: Also, I found adding `, ownerAffiliations: OWNER` inside the `repositories(...)` restricted it to repos that I own, which are the ones that matter here.